# Is Adobe Air available on sony ericson xperia mini pro

Tags: adobe-air, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I'm planning to buy a Sony Xperia Mini Pro, with the physical keyboard, not the x10 mini, but the latest one.

The sony xperia mini pro is not listed on [Adobe's flash compatible devices list](http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/certified_devices/)

I plan to use it for development and I also plan to develop apps in Adobe AIR, can somebody with a Sony Xperia Mini Pro confirm they are able to download and install [Adobe AIR](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.air) from the market, and run AIR and flash apps on this phone?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The official Sony page](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/products/mobilephones/overview/xperia-mini-pro) says it has Flash preinstalled (look on the "In business" tab, "Fast and full Internet" section).

The Xperia Mini Pro meets [the specs for Adobe Air](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/906/cpsid_90612.html), so I see no reason to believe you couldn't download Air as well.

Comment: this is also what I believe, but as AIR availability is most important for me, I'd like to have confirmation from an actual user of this phone.

Comment: @Smugrik If I can find it, I'll spoof the XMP's device fingerprint on my phone and see if I can download AIR.